# Neatshow JS Plugin not showing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I included neatshow.min.js I am doing everything the script instruction says. First says I hide images with css and then you I must show with the script.

this is my instructions

```
$(window).ready(function(){ 
    $('img').neatshow();
});
```

javascript error is occured

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'neatshow'
```

something is wrong in this program?

[Neatshow](http://stevepapa.com/neatshowjs) http://stevepapa.com/neatshowjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found help in other forum, the problem was this

```
$('img').neatshow();
```

must be in case sensitive

```
$('img').neatShow();
```

working as it must, very nice....

Answer (score 0):

Chrome return this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'neatShow'
```

When `jquery.js` is include **but `neatshow.js` is not include**.

Did you had include js in your html page ? Like this :

```
<script src="http://stevepapa.com/neatshowjs/neatshow.min.js"></script>
```

(Maybe your link is broken).

Comment: This is included <script src="http://stevepapa.com/neatshowjs/neatshow.min.js "></script>